# How can I rotate an EV3 motor an exact number of degrees using RobotC?

Tags: ev3, programming, motor, robotc

I'm trying to rotate the motor of an EV3 by an angle of 50°. I can't.
How I can rotate a NXT/EV3 motor by a given angle using RobotC?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of your [previous question](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/6009/56) - or have you switched from NXC to RobotC? Are you using the interactive servo motors or the medium/large servo motors?

Comment: Also - can you post an example of what you have tried - RobotC should support sending [specific angles to servos](http://www.robotc.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=5764&sid=ca6339af082e78c7d4c4d3b856e76c71#p5764) assuming you've configured them correctly...

Comment: You can also look at [LeJOS](http://www.lejos.org) - its API for sure allows a motor to turn a specific amount of degrees through the rotate() method. On an instance of a regulated motor this should give you a very accurate rotation.

Answer (score 3):

The command that you are looking for is setMotorTarget as shown in the documentation [here](http://help.robotc.net/WebHelpMindstorms/index.htm#Topics/Function_Library_-_LEGO_EV3/Motors_-_EV3.htm).

Essentially, you need to set the target rotation for the motor in degrees and then wait for the movement to take place:

```
//Sets motorA target to 50 degrees at a speed of 100
setMotorTarget(motorA, 50, 100);
// Waits for movement to complete
waitUntilMotorStop(motorA);
```